# Postgres database says database exist but I cannot Alter owner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, vps, database-migration

This is my first VPS and first rails project ever.

Inside of postgres console:

```
postgres=# \list
                                     List of databases
      Name       |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 blog_production | blog     | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 postgres        | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0       | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
                 |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1       | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
                 |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)

postgres=# ALTER DATABASE blog_development OWNER TO watashi;
ERROR:  database "blog_development" does not exist
```

How can it not exist when it obviously is on the list?  How can I drop this database? and if I can it hurt my vps?

Link to site is: [www.morningharwood.com](http://www.morningharwood.com)
it doesnt error out until [www.morningharwood.com/works](http://www.morningharwood.com/works)

Comment: it needed a semicolen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails can't find the `works` table, it should have been created as part of your `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate` command, what was the output of that?

Also check that you are running the rails server in production mode.

Comment: I accually dont think i created a database for my VPS... do you know the commands for this?

Comment: the tutorial I went through just made the connection through cap deploy work but I'm so bad I dont even kno whow to create a postgres database... I know i have to create it... make an owner and then attactch that owner to the database then migrate yeah? is there anything I'm missing

Comment: When I go into Postgres and run \dt I comes up with no relations; that means no database yeah?

Comment: also the output of the RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate did printed out nothing

Comment: try `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:create` (then run migrations again)

Comment: also check the production database config in `config/database.yml`, that's how Rails knows which database to connect to

Comment: since it's a vps I must go into the postgres console and then set and create a user and password and set them to owners yeah?

Comment: I know the user name and password i set.  and i set it through ssh in vim.  So those must be set altered from postgres after rake db:create... sorry for the verbosity; however, I always feel as if, I'm going to ruin my vps.

Comment: Yeah, do that then make sure to set the same user/pw combo in `config/database.yml` under production

Comment: deployer@vps:~/apps/blog/current$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:create
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "watashi"

Comment: Should I create the database manually through postgres console?
#create user watashi with password 'secret';
# create database blog_production owner watashi;

Comment: postgres=#  create database blog_production owner watashi;
ERROR:  database "blog_production" already exists
postgres=# \d
No relations found.

Comment: what is this witch craft

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33737/discussion-between-matthew-harwood-and-shevaun)